# What is the algorithm to permute a set of elements in to a fixed length?

Tags: combinatorics

for example {abc, d, e, f, xy} and fixed length 5

the output should be

abced, abcef, abcdf, abcxy, xydef

further is for multiple length 5 and 6

append the output list is abcedf, abcxyd, abcxye, abcxyf

any algorithm doing this?

Comment: You could just try all possible combinations and only keep those whose length is in the desired range.

Comment: This is more appropriate for a computer science/programming site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual method is via [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) via a [backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).  Basically starting with an empty string, we extend it in all possible ways, and if those extensions are not long enough, we extend those in all possible ways, and so on recursively.  (If the extensions are too long, we do not continue that case.)  Here's a [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) implementation:

```
A:=["abc","d","e","f","xy"];
used:=List(A,i->false);

find_strings:=function(current_string)
  local i,substr,new_string;
  for i in [1..Size(A)] do
    if(used[i]) then continue; fi;
    substr:=A[i];
    new_string:=Concatenation(current_string,substr);
    if(Length(new_string)=5) then
      Print(new_string,"\n");
    elif(Length(new_string)<5) then
      used[i]:=true;
      find_strings(new_string);
      used[i]:=false;
    fi;
  od;
end;;
```

which outputs:

```
abcde
abcdf
abced
abcef
abcfd
abcfe
abcxy
dabce
dabcf
deabc
defxy
dexyf
dfabc
dfexy
dfxye
dxyef
dxyfe
eabcd
eabcf
edabc
edfxy
edxyf
efabc
efdxy
efxyd
exydf
exyfd
fabcd
fabce
fdabc
fdexy
fdxye
feabc
fedxy
fexyd
fxyde
fxyed
xyabc
xydef
xydfe
xyedf
xyefd
xyfde
xyfed
```

Slight modifications of this will give the length $5$ and $6$ case.

Comment: this make me want to memorize depth first search, i never thought depth first search can apply on this, it seems that i do not truly understand the depth first search when i think it is only for search.